# Flow type for a function parameter that is instance of a class

Tags: flowtype

Given:

```
// @flow

declare interface IFoo {
    test();
}

class Foo implements IFoo {
    test () {
        console.log('in test');
    }
}
```

if i had a function:

```
// some function
async function demo (argA: string, argB: INSTANCE_OF_Foo) { ... }
```

how can i tell flow that `argB` is "instance of class that implements IFoo"? in other words if the usage of function `demo` had to be like

```
const foo: IFoo = new Foo();
demo('bla' foo);
```

How can i ensure what get's passed to `demo` is instance of a class that implements `IFoo`?

Comment: I think it should be declare interface IFoo { test: Function }

Answer (score 0):

type script interface is ignored at runtime, it is only used at compile time for type checking. So there is no way you can check whether the Foo is implemented with IFoo.
But you can check whether foo is an instance of Foo class.

Answer (score 0):

So it depends on what you seek: you can either ensure the argument implements `IFoo`:

```
async function demo (argA: string, argB: IFoo)
```

, or the argument is an instance of the class `Foo`:

```
async function demo (argA: string, argB: Foo)
```

But I must say, it's not really clear why you need to require an instance instead of an interface (which I think is the way to go here).

You can play with this easily at [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAmBTAxtAhgJzaAJYB2ALmrpNhgQJIBissoA3oqKANTkDOpAXKAAUASlABeAHygAbrEIpEAX2RZsPHqEbNCAWwAO0NLrRlNDJq3ZEUE0AEYATMg69SwsWw4cMsYj1gjADo4AHMhAHISUDcIkWsVFWRIAFdiDFJCP1B0XWYhPFCAQUE+XBJQgBpQQoAhQW1Pa19-QLQQ2HC6oIV4jm63UWVktIys4hzjfMKS0DKK6rrBC1gmjhBQAFEAJW2AeW3QAFppFoDgsILcUNqelD6a69vB+KSz90hLcVBiNHgtJhDXKwSIAIxwEWqn1WQA).

Hope this helps!